# How to start Redis inside Docker with Docker Toolbox on Windows 7?

Tags: docker, redis

I have **Docker Toolbox** running on a **Windows 7** machine. I downloaded [Redis DOI](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) and typed the given command to run Redis:

```
docker run --name some-redis -d -p 6379:6379 redis
```

However, this doesn't seem to start Redis as a service. When I type `docker ps` the container is not listed and typing `docker ps -a` gives the status `Exited (127) 7 minutes ago` for `some-redis`.

Can somebody tell me how to start the Redis server on a Windows machine with Docker Toolbox?

**Edit:**

Here the logs, but to be honest, I'm new to Docker and also no specialist in Virtual machines or Linux. Maybe somebody can translate these messages into simple to perform actions?

```
1:C 18 Dec 2023 12:35:18.912 # WARNING Memory overcommit must be enabled! Without it, a background save or replication may fail under low memory condition. Being disabled, it can also cause failures without low memory condition, see https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/1328. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
1:C 18 Dec 2023 12:35:18.912 * oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 18 Dec 2023 12:35:18.912 * Redis version=7.2.3, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 18 Dec 2023 12:35:18.912 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
1:M 18 Dec 2023 12:35:18.913 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:M 18 Dec 2023 12:35:18.913 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 18 Dec 2023 12:35:18.913 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
1:M 18 Dec 2023 12:35:18.913 # Fatal: Can't initialize Background Jobs. Error message: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Did you look for error messages? What does `docker logs some-redis` tell you?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @larsks. I've added the logs, but as stated in the edit section, I'm completely new to the Docker game. So any hints would be really nice, since I have no clue at all. I just tried to follow instructions, but that doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: I see two messages there warning about problematic `sysctl` settings. I don't know if that's the cause of the failure, but probably worth addressing those first and seeing if that resolves things. Just searching for the failure message ("Can't initialize background jobs...") leads to several useful looking results.

Comment: Well, I've spent half a day to learn that development under Windows is nothing else but tideous ;). Many thanks anyways, I have googled the errors (thanks to your help I now know the docker logs command), and could target the first warning by running `sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1` on the VM which runs Docker. The FATAL error was finally corrected after trying multiple redis images. The one which starts in my Docker Toolbox VM without the FATAL error is: `7.0.14-alpine`. Many thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @Slevin for sharing the tip! Yes, the "-alpine" version is free from this problem. Currently switched to latest - 7.2.4-alpine. You saved my day.